# 'Git is not installed' on intellij

Tags: java, git, github, intellij-idea, intellij-14

Hi i am trying to link up my a java group project from github to intellij. However i keep getting this issue with Git, i download it but then i try again and it asks me to download it again?

[image]

I've looked up the 'Paths to Git executable' and this is what it shows

[image]

But i really don't understand why this is not working. I am new to github and would really appreciate some help on this!

Comment: Did you separately download and install Git on your device?

Comment: When you set git up did you hit the test button?  
I get this issue intermittently, I go IntelliJ's properties and test that git is installed, and then restart IntelliJ using the 'invalidate caches and restart' option and usually once IntelliJ restarts git is detected correctly and I can continue to work.  I am on MacOS.  It is one of an increasing number of issues/concerns I have about IntelliJ.

Comment: Yeah i just downloaded a Git-2.30.2-64-bit and also a GitHubDesktopSetpup on my laptop, not really sure what they do though

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I noticed that I had the same problem after installing Github Desktop for a few days. I uninstalled it because I was just testing it anyway and found my git in my system by the following code:

```
which git
```

That command showed me the following output:

```
/usr/bin/git
```

So I entered this into 'Path to Git executable' in the Preferences > Version Control > Git. And restarted the IDE. Everything works now...

Comment: this didn't work for me. Path was correct. Deactivating and reactivating the Git plugin helped

Comment: Worked for me even without restarting IntelliJ. Don't forget to click "Apply".

Answer (score 15):

For me, I can see the git is installed on me, but somehow Android Studio could not find it.

in Android Studio, `File` -> `Invalidate Cache` -> `Invalidate and Restart`

Will fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

Preferences -> Plugins
Deactivate the bundled Git plugin, restart PhpStorm and activate it again

This solved the issue on my Mac.

Comment: @NickMcCurdy This answer also specified to activate it again, so it would not prevent them from using git.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have a dedicated Git client installed. The official client can be found at: https://git-scm.com/

Comment: Ive downloaded a 'Git-2.30.2-64-bit' from the website but i still dont think it works

Answer (score 0):

Manually updating the path for `git` in Intellij worked for me.